# SSIS Run multiple Execute Process tasks in parallel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, executeprocesstask

I have a package that needs to run the separate `Execute process task` that make command line calls in parallel.

I have tested this and SSIS seems to only allow them to execute consecutively (One call waits for the before it finishes despite being in separate simultaneous flows)  Has anyone had any luck getting SSIS to run this in parallel

Comment: I provided an answer to solved it. But still waiting for a reply!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `Sequence Container` and inside it add multiple `Execute process Task` *(separate tasks)* and do not connect any task inside the container. Just connect the container with other items.

And check your Package `MaxConcurrentExecutables` property

[image]